# How can I check in an angular view if an object's property is an object itself?

Tags: angularjs

I'm building some form views with angular and need to run over some nested objects.

I've run into an issue and can't figure out exactly what I'm missing.

```
<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="Main">

     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ob">
       {{key}}
       <div ng-if="angular.isObject(ob[key])">
         angular.isObject() returns true!
       </div>
       <div ng-if="!angular.isObject(ob[key])">
         angular.isObject() returns false!
       </div>

       <div ng-if="typeof(ob[key]) === 'object'">
           typeof is object!
       </div>

       <div ng-if="typeof(ob[key]) !== 'object'">
           typeof is not object!
       </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.ob = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 'asd',
  prop3: {
    subprop1: 'one',
    subprop2: 'two'
  }
};
```

In the code above I'm trying to use `angular.isObject` to detect whether the property is an object, so I can go into another loop afterwards. Both ng-ifs resolve to false, even if my third property is an object. Same while using `typeof`.

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLEVLr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `angular` in template. Template is evaluated against scope object, not global one (e.g. `window`, which has angular property as global variable).

If you really want to you can simply expose reference to the angular like this:

```
$scope.angular = angular
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJdNzV?editors=1010

But better approach is to expose only function that you actually need:

```
$scope.isObject = angular.isObject
```

and use it in template like this:

```
ng-if="isObject(value)"
```

Comment: Upvoted for using only function that is actually needed in view. Every thing that bounds to $scope has also watchers assigned to it. So performance issues will be there if you try to expose all angular core to UI with $scope.